# e: Could not find "ProjectNameToken" in [...]

Tags: kotlin, gradle, kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-multiplatform-mobile, gradle-kts

I have tackled a weird exception that throws the following when I run the `linkDebugFrameworkIosArm64` Gradle task or any architecture variant of it for a KMM module;

```bash
e: Could not find "Yekta" in [/Users/yektasarioglu/Desktop/workspace/kotlin/kotlin-multiplatform/personal/yektasarioglu-app/yektasarioglu-shared/layer/kmm_regular_framework, /Users/yektasarioglu/.konan/klib, /Users/yektasarioglu/.konan/kotlin-native-prebuilt-macos-aarch64-1.7.20/klib/common, /Users/yektasarioglu/.konan/kotlin-native-prebuilt-macos-aarch64-1.7.20/klib/platform/ios_arm64]

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':yektasarioglu-shared:layer:kmm_regular_framework:linkDebugFrameworkIosArm64'.
> Compilation finished with errors
```

I searched almost everything related to it and could not find any other instances or related issues. Have you ever encountered these kinds of problems or related ones? Do you have any idea why this problem may occur? Thanks.

Comment: Can you attach a link to your project?

Answer (score 2):

I finally figured out how to solve this ambiguous exception. It turns out that a variable inside **settings.gradle.kts** file `rootProject.name = "Yekta Sarioglu - App"` was causing this. So, I removed the whitespaces between words, and it worked. And honestly, I don't know why it did. In the end, I'm glad that it worked and saved me from myself to turn the project into a mess to find out what was the main cause of it. And also, anyone who knows why would be appreciated.

Comment: The "why" could be an unescaped parameter to a shell command, the space ends the parameter so it takes only `Yetka` in your case instead of the full string.